# TSQL Convert rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a query that returns some data that looks like this:

```
Description
----------
Thing1
Thing2
Thing3
Thing4
Thing5
Thing6
Thing7
```

I would like to make the data look like this:

```
Desc1    Desc2  Desc3
-----    -----  -----
Thing1   Thing2 Thing3
Thing4   Thing5 Thing6
Thing7
```

Could someone provide an example on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the logic to determine what goes in each column?

Comment: I just want it to sequentially put the data into the columns until there is no more data.

Comment: Data in the table is not inherently ordered - do you have an `id` field, or just order by `Description` (which won't work once you hit 10)?

Comment: @functionalCode But what determines `Thing3` goes in `Desc3`? Why not `Desc1`?

Comment: The order in which a "thing" goes into a "desc" field doesn't matter.  I really just want to transform the data into the column structure instead of just being a big list.

Comment: So you want three columns of "stuff" instead of one column?

Comment: -1 for ***no*** effort.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: To be honest, there are challenges where it's difficult to  break the first ground after all. The question is at least clear and interesting .

Comment: @TimSchmelter But there are ***too many*** just like it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You stated the comments that the order of the data in the `Desc` columns does not matter.

If that is the case, then you can use the following which implement `NTILE` and `row_number()`:

```
;with cte as
(
  select description,
    'desc'+cast(ntile(3) over(order by Description) as varchar(10)) col
  from yt
)
select desc1, desc2, desc3
from
(
  select description, col,
    row_number() over(partition by col order by col) rn
  from cte
) d
pivot
(
  max(description)
  for col in (desc1, desc2, desc3)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aec0e/13).

The [`NTILE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) function distributes the rows into separate groups. Once that is done, then apply a `row_number()` to give a unique number to each row while grouping.

This gives a result:

```
|  DESC1 |  DESC2 |  DESC3 |
----------------------------
| Thing1 | Thing4 | Thing6 |
| Thing2 | Thing5 | Thing7 |
| Thing3 | (null) | (null) |
```

Comment: @PinnyM LOL, I was typing when the question was first posted. I was just waiting to hear if the order of the data mattered. :)

Comment: I think the order should be different, at least the desired result has an inherent order which is derived from the `Description` column(from left to right).

Comment: @TimSchmelter They stated in the comments that the order didn't matter, they just wanted the data in columns.

Comment: @bluefeet: In that case +1, however, i was interested in a solution to this order problem(say vertical to horizontal).

Comment: @TimSchmelter They need to explain the logic that they want the order in.  I didn't post until they said that they didn't care

Answer (score 3):

Another approach of doing it, if the order does matter, and skipping PIVOT function:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Description])+2) /3 AS RowID,
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Description])+2) % 3 +1 AS ColID,  
        [Description] 
    FROM Table1
)
SELECT 
     MIN(CASE WHEN ColID = 1 THEN [Description] END) DESC1
    ,MIN(CASE WHEN ColID = 2 THEN [Description] END) DESC2
    ,MIN(CASE WHEN ColID = 3 THEN [Description] END) DESC3
FROM CTE
GROUP BY RowID
```

[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b676a/1)

Comment: FYI, You are still pivoting, you are are just not using the PIVOT function.

Comment: @bluefeet Yes, off course, bad phrasing but that's exactly what I meant, thanks. ... edited that part

Answer (score 1):

I used the base data from the sqlfiddle of @NenadZivkovic to provide a different solution

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b676a/15

```
WITH Numbered AS 
(
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Description) as rn,
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Description) - 1) % 3 as colid,
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Description) - 1) / 3 as line,
    Description 
  FROM Table1
)
SELECT desc1.description as DESC1, desc2.description as DESC2, desc3.description as DESC3
FROM   (SELECT line, description FROM Numbered WHERE colid=0) as desc1
LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT line, description FROM Numbered WHERE colid=1) as desc2
ON (desc1.line = desc2.line)
LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT line, description FROM Numbered WHERE colid=2) as desc3
ON (desc2.line = desc3.line)
```